# How to import a file that starts with numbers (227exercise.py)?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to import the file `227exercise.py`, but keep getting following error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `importlib`.

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module("227exercise")
print(repr(module))
# <module '227exercise' from '/home/ubuntu/227exercise.py'>
```

However, it is still strongly recommended that you name your python files with valid identifiers (they can't begin with digits).

Comment: @John You can click the grey tick beside this answer to mark it as "accepted". See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)